# Password pattern wont accept this special characters like <>,./'";

Tags: html, regex, passwords

I use this pattern in input tag type password to accept a strong password. "Must contain at least one  number, one uppercase and lowercase letter, and one special character ,minimum of 8 characters, and maximum of 26 characters". But when I inserted one of these characters `<>,./'";` the field title keep appearing. I would like to implement all special characters in my registration form

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: They are not in your list, so why would expect them to work?

Comment: would you tell me where can i put it on the pattern @mplungjan?

Comment: A good place to start would be a regex tool like https://regex101.com/. You can input your pattern and it will give you a full explanation of how it works. Perhaps you could give it a try, see if you can figure out where to add your additional special characters? Then if it still doesn't work, I'd recommend editing your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=.*[0-9])         require one digit anywhere
(?=.*[a-z])         require one lowercase letter anywhere
(?=.*[A-Z])         require one uppercase letter anywhere
(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])  require one symbol anywhere
^.{8,26}$           match any string of 8 to 26 characters
```

Combine all of these together and you get:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z]).{8,26}$
```

This, of course, counts anything that isn't a letter from A to Z or a digit as a special character, including accented letters, letters from other alphabets, and whitespace.